# D3: get dimensions of DOM node while appending elements

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Working with [d3.js](https://d3js.org/), I'm trying to create a set of nodes, append an SVG `circle` and `text` element to each node and then re-position the text element (set its `dx` and `dy` attributes). Specifically, I'd like to center the text element inside the SVG.

In my current implementation, the SVG elements are created/appended first, then I'm iterating over the nodes a second time to measure each text element and transform it accordingly:

```
///////////////////////////////////////
// Create node elements from data... //
///////////////////////////////////////

const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const data_nodes = state.data.nodes;

const elements = canvas.svg
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "nodes")
  //////
  .selectAll(".node") // <— create empty selection
  .data(data_nodes)
  .enter()
  //////
  .append("svg")      // <— added nested SVG
  .attr("class", "node");

////////////////////////////////
// ...append circle & text... //
////////////////////////////////

elements.append("circle").attr("r", (data) => data.size / 2);
elements.append("text").text((data) => data.text.content)

////////////////////
// ...center text //
////////////////////

for (let node of elements.nodes()) {
  const textEl = node.querySelector("text");
  const width = textEl.getBoundingClientRect().width;
  const height = textEl.getBoundingClientRect().height;
  //////
  textEl.setAttribute("dx", (width / 2) * -1);
  textEl.setAttribute("dy", height / 2);
}
```

This works, but I'm wondering if it's possible to reference the DOM node corresponding to each appended text element while/after appending it and dynamically setting `dx`/`dy` then?